# Read from disk after write instead of cache

Tags: c, linux

Here's the task I'm trying to perform on a linux host, with a C program:

Write random data to the disk, call `fysnc()` to flush data to disk, then read back what was written `from the disk` to ensure the disk controller wrote the data correctly. The problem I am running into is that reads appear to be answered by server-side caching rather than from the device itself. Here's what I've already tried:

```
 1. O_DIRECT (a gigantic pain in the butt, abandoned)
 2. posix_fadvise(fd,0,0,POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)
 3. posix_fadvise(fd,0,0,POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE)
 4. O_SYNC
 5. O_ASYNC
```

In every case, `iostat` shows `0 rrqm/s` and thousands of write requests. I could be a woefully uninformed linux user, but it is my belief that if no IOs are shown in rrqm/s then reads are being answered by the OS cache instead of the device itself.

"Why not use iozone or iometer, or any of the billions of other tools that already stress disks?" Well, to be honest, if HP-UX's HAZARD worked on anything except HP-UX, I would, but nothing else comes close to what hazard can do, so I'm making my own.

Comment: It might help to post the read code you have written that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the equivalent of the following shell commands:

```
sync                               # Instruct all data to get flushed to disk
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches  # Instruct VM system to clear caches
```

and then try reading the file again.

One way to do it from C would be something approximating:

```
sync();
int fd = open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC)
write(fd, "3\n");
close(fd);
```

Comment: Niiicceee. That gave me what I needed. I had seen that drop_caches call, but I never thought to open it within the program. I had a blonde moment. The only step I don't make use of is the `close()` call, but I call `fsync()` to ensure the command makes it there before I begin readback. Now I'm seeing all write IO stop and read IO take over. Perfection! :D

Answer (score 1):

You should not go thru the [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) to test a disk. You should read and write the [raw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rawdisk) partitions (e.g. `/dev/sdc5`)

On most current Linux systems and hardware, disks have a [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) interface. You should use it, see [smartmontools](http://www.smartmontools.org/) and study its source code. (I guess that there are some [ioctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) related to that.)

Comment: This is what I am doing. I am opening /dev/sd<letter>.